# How to get elements across different webpages on the click of a button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I wanted to know if it's possible to get elements of the same class across different HTML files, to be displayed on the click of a button or link, in the current web page.
I'm actually looking at something similar to a filter. Just that the images are across different web pages and each of them belong to a particular category(which i used as their class names). So, i want to be able to view the elements of the same category(class names) in the current webpage, on clicking the link. I need some ideas and solutions. Already have a logic as to what to do, but not sure if it'll implement correctly. Would like some help. Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by *"different web pages"*, are these pages from the same origin or some other domain etc?

Comment: You could get the HTML from a different page using the jQuery.get() method (https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/).  However you could run in issues if it isn't the same origin.  Also, if there is any script associated with these elements they won't function so you need to take that into consideration.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'll visit the link. I'm grateful. @vbguyny

Comment: Yeah well they are from the same domain. Like different webpages of the same website. But you don't have to worry. I got a nice solution from Kolby .Thanks. @adeneo

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use ajax to get the html of another page, and then `.find('.classname')` to find the class you're looking for.

```
$.get( "yoururl.html", function( data ) {
    $(data).find('.className').html();
});
```

The data that gets returned is the html of the url entered. From there just traverse the html to find the node you're looking for and do what you need to with it.

https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/

Comment: Please add `same origin` info

Comment: Thanks very much for the help. I understand it now. I'll implement it well. Thanks once again. @Kolby